# SunGard Investran OLE DB provider Usage

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I need to use the OLEDB provider (for SunGard Investran) from my C# application and fetch data from reports with parameters. I am able to connect the database but not able to fetch data. The application crashes with exception code c0000005. Please provide some guidance on how to use this.

I am running this on 64-bit win server 2008 R2.
Here is the code that I am using. It crashes on the last line of fetching the data.

```
string connect = "Provider=ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider;Password=xxxxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Data Source=xxxxxx;";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.CommandText = "[ReportFolder].[ReportName]";
                //conn.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);


            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to add a code snippet of the crash. It will be very hard to help you w/o it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the syntax. It was OLEDB provider specific. Here is the syntax in case anyone else is using it.

```
cmd.CommandText = "\"ReportFolder\".\"ReportName\" FLAGS[/SILENT]";
```

Parameters can also be added like this.

```
cmd.CommandText = "\"ReportFolder\".\"ReportName\" \"ParamName=value\" FLAGS[/SILENT]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no real command from the command text...

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from SomeTable where ... ";
```

If "ReportFolder" is the table in your database and "ReportName" is the column, then if you want all records, you don't need a WHERE clause.

```
cmd.CommandText = "select ReportName from ReportFolder";
```

Now, if you want to add parameters, such as types of reports, or whatever, be sure to properly parameterize them, but I am not familiar with the "place-holder" syntax of your database.  For example, in Visual FoxPro (VFP), "?" is a place-holder, in SQL-Server its "@", in SyBase Advantage its ":" such as the query would become

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from YourTable where Something = @someParmToApply";
cmd.Parameters.Add( "someParmToApply", "this thing" );
```

then continue your execution of the query... If you have multiple parameters, just make sure you keep them in the same sequence as they appear in the query... it makes it easier to follow.

Comment: I already tried using "select * from ReportFolder.ReportName". "ReportName" is the table name, "ReportFolder" is schema. It throws an oledb exception with message "'ftiRSOLEDB.RSOLEDBProvider' failed with no error message available, result code: -2147220941(0x80040233)."